# Difference remove object and becoming nil for UserDefaults - Swift

Tags: swift

I want to clear userdefault but I could not understand difference between

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(nil, forKey: "token") // when should i use this
```

---

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "token") // when should i use this
```

Thanks

Comment: The first one is keeping the property but setting its value to nil. So either you want "token" to be `nil` or not exist at all in UserDefaults, that is all up to you and what you mean by clearing.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson Thanks this is the first time you liked my question. :) 
So if i want to set token and delete it something like this: After logging in the app should keep a login session until the user explicitly logs out.
Which one is make more sense ?

Comment: In that situation I don't think it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No difference at all.

If you wanna remove object, use second variant for better readability

First one useful when you have an optional value and don't want care if it's nil, like

```
var a: String? = "hello"
UserDefaults.standard.set(a, forKey: "token")
b = nil
UserDefaults.standard.set(a, forKey: "token")
```

Otherwise you would have to check value and choose to either insert or delete

Comment: mission completed ! Please have a look your email, i sent you